# ThreeJS refelction wiht 2 cameras

Tags: three.js

I want to achieve a very simple reflection. I have a object in scene and floor underneath it. Main camera looks at the scene. And the reflection camera looks underneath. Problem is i cannot figure out how to position the reflection camera and what should be its up vector. maincamera and reflectioncamera will have the same lookat.

Can anyone help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365236/how-can-i-use-reflection-in-three-js Duplicate, I think?

Comment: No cubecamera. Only 2 normal perspective cameras.